# how to convertt the html chartjs charts to image

Tags: javascript, html, image, pdf, charts

I have created an HTML page that includes charts I have created charts using ChartJS Which is running perfectly fine but when I am trying to convert that HTML to pdf that chart is not visible after pdf conversion

JS

```
var farm_score = document.getElementById('farm_score').innerHTML;
farm_score = farm_score.replace(/'/g, '"');
final_farm_score = JSON.parse(farm_score)

const chartWidth = document.querySelector('.chartBox').getBoundingClientRect().width-46;
const ctx = document.getElementById('farm_score_data').getContext('2d');
const gradientSegment = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, chartWidth, 0);
gradientSegment.addColorStop(0.25, 'red');
gradientSegment.addColorStop(0.50, 'DarkOrange');
gradientSegment.addColorStop(0.75, 'lightgreen');
gradientSegment.addColorStop(1, 'green');

var remain_fs = 900 - final_farm_score['farm_score']


    // setup
    const data = {

      datasets: [{
        label: 'Weekly Sales',
        data: [final_farm_score['farm_score'], remain_fs],
        backgroundColor: [
          gradientSegment,
          'rgba(239, 239, 239, 1)'
        ],

        borderWidth: 0,
        cutout:'90%',
        circumference:180,
        rotation:270
      }]
    };


    //gaugeChartText

    const gaugeChartText = {
        id : 'gaugeChartText',
        afterDatasetsDraw(chart, args, pluginOptions){
            const {ctx, data, chartArea: {top, bottom, left, right, width, height}, scales: {r} }= chart;
            ctx.save();
            const xCoor  = chart.getDatasetMeta(0).data[0].x;
            const yCoor  = chart.getDatasetMeta(0).data[0].y;
            const score = data.datasets[0].data[0];


            let rating ;
            if(score<=300) {rating = 'D';}
            if(score >300 && score <=499) {rating = 'D';}
            if(score >= 500 && score <=649) {rating = 'C';}
            if(score >= 650 && score <=749) {rating = 'B';}
            if(score >= 750 && score <=900) {rating = 'A';}
            if(score>900) {rating = 'A';}

            let ratingcolor;
            if(score<=300) {ratingcolor = 'red';}
            if(score >300 && score <=499) {ratingcolor = 'red';}
            if(score >= 500 && score <=649) {ratingcolor = 'DarkOrange';}
            if(score >= 650 && score <=749) {ratingcolor = 'lightgreen';}
            if(score >= 750 && score <=900) {ratingcolor = 'green';}
            if(score>900) {rating = 'green';}



            function textLabel(text, x, y, fontSize, textBaseLine, textAlign, color){

              ctx.font = `${fontSize}px sans-serif`;
              ctx.fillStyle = color;
              ctx.textBaseLine = textBaseLine;
              ctx.textAlign = textAlign;
              ctx.fillText(text, x, y);
            }

            textLabel('300', left, yCoor+3, 7, 'top', 'left', '#666');
            textLabel('900', right, yCoor+3, 7, 'top', 'right','#666');
            textLabel(score, xCoor, yCoor-10, 15, 'bottom', 'center', '#666');
            textLabel(rating, xCoor, yCoor-30, 20, 'bottom', 'center', ratingcolor);


        }
    }


    // config
    const config = {
      type: 'doughnut',
      data,
      options: {
      aspectRatio:1.5,
      plugins:{
      legend:{
        display:true
      },
      tooltip:{
      enabled:false
      }
      }
      },

      plugins:[ gaugeChartText ]
    };

    // render init block
    const myChart = new Chart(
      document.getElementById('farm_score_data'),
      config
    );
```

CSS

```
* {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-family: sans-serif;
      }


      .chartBox {
        width: 120px;
        height:80px;
        padding: 20px;
        background: white;
      }
```

HTML

```
<div class="chartBox"><canvas id="farm_score_data"></canvas></div>
```

After google i found that i have to convert the js chart to image I am unable to do it I any can help
`